# MongoDB - Metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I integrated my rails application with MongoDB using `mongo` gem. I would like to know how I can store metadata about each collection.

```
  def initialize(db_params)
    db = Mongo::Connection.new(connection_uri[:host], connection_uri[:port])
    @collection = db.db(db_params[:key]).collection(db_params[:collection])
  end
```

More precisely I want to add some metadata during creating new collection and then be able to read that before other database actions like find.

Comment: Could you give us some example. To be honest I don't get it with the text above^^. Do you want to store some extra informations like for example a collection description to the collection?

Comment: Yes exactly. For each collection I need additional description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case we could go for two solutions:

1. using flexibility of dynamic schema create a meta doc with `_id="meta"`, and store there all requred data
2. create `meta` collection and in each document store info about collection,, `_id="collection name"`

per manual:

```
db.createCollection(<name>, { capped: <boolean>,
                              autoIndexId: <boolean>,
                              size: <number>,
                              max: <number>,
                              storageEngine: <document>,
                              validator: <document>,
                              validationLevel: <string>,
                              validationAction: <string>,
                              indexOptionDefaults: <document> } )
```

Any comments welcome!

Comment: when I call `db.getCollectionInfos()` there is a list of all collections. As I can see there is a `options` field.
{
  "name" : "my_test_collection",
  "options" : {
   
  }
 }. So maybe is some way to pass my metadata just inside this field?

Comment: @mike927 unfortunately there is no room for that - see edit

Comment: yes you are right, it looks like I have to use one of two your proposals.